# Hibernate query is not returning updated result

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project, I have two parts UI and Engine. Both are accessing same Database but different hbm.xml files and hibernate connections. If I try to update some table value from UI, the Engine side query does not return updated value.

Is it some general problem? Below is my code. I checked it online and found something about Hibernate Cache. I do not know how to remove it. Please help.

```
public CgUssdGatewayConf getGwConfig(Long gwId)
{
    logger.info("GW ID : "+gwId);
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(CgUssdGatewayConf.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("gwId", gwId));
    //Now checking while cache loading time.
    //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", Constants.GW_STATUS_ENABLE));

    List<CgUssdGatewayConf> list = (List<CgUssdGatewayConf>) criteria.list();
    if(list != null && !list.isEmpty())
    {
        CgUssdGatewayConf cgUssdGatewayConf = list.get(0);
        logger.info("GW ID : "+cgUssdGatewayConf.getGwId()+ " :: Name : "+cgUssdGatewayConf.getGwName() + " :: Status : "+cgUssdGatewayConf.getStatus());
        return cgUssdGatewayConf;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and my hibernate config is-

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Mysql Config -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/consentgateway</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">cg</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">cg123</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxAdministrativeTaskTime">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>CgUssdGatewayConf.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: have you enabled your 2nlevel cache (hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache) ?

Comment: I added this line
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>

But it's still sending the old values.

Answer (score 1):

First level caching is default thing in Hibernate and always Associates with the Session object. Hibernate uses this cache by default. Here, it processes one transaction after another one. Mainly it reduces the number of SQL queries it needs to generate within a given transaction. That is instead of updating after every modification done in the transaction, it updates the transaction only at the end of the transaction.

for reflecting cached queries's effect Hibernate Transaction needs to be committed.

I don't know whether you have committed or not but check for it.

```
Transaction trnsction = session.beginTransaction();

update queries

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Can this be a problem? Because I tried updating multiple times giving many values each time. Still the very first value of DB, the one present at the start of module, is coming. So I do not think that transaction commit can be a problem, can it?

Comment: I have faced this problem before. I was updating the data without starting transaction and committing. you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The first level cache cannot be disabled at all.
However you can `evict` the object from the [session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) before loading it. As the result the object will be reread from the database.

```
Session.evict(entity);
```

Or `refresh` object. Also loads the latest object state from the database and rewrites the existing one in the session.

```
Session.refresh(entity);
```

Comment: I am doing like this-
getSession().evict(cgUssdGatewayConf);
getSession().refresh(cgUssdGatewayConf);
where cgUssdGatewayConf is the Hibernate Model class object.

but still no progress.

Comment: Are you sure your Engine changes have been committed before UI part tries to retrieve them?

Comment: You can also try to run Session.clear() as the first line in getGwConfig method. This completely clears out the hibernate session.

Comment: Try to check whether changes have been commited by manually run SQL using some SQL Developer studio.

Comment: In the same java file where I am trying to get the data through Hibernate, I am doing one call to DB by JDBC. JDBC is returning correct (updated) result. But Hibernate call is returning old data.

I checked by getSession().clear(); But no success. I will check my files one by one now.

Comment: If you did getSession().clear(), then the problem is not in Hibernate. I guess, hibernate get an object from some different location or uses different SQL that you might not expect. Try to log hibernate SQL and run it manually and see what is wrong.